# How to set up subdomain on my dedicated server on CentOS with apache

Tags: apache, centos, dedicated-server

I have core managed dedicated server on liquidweb.com. I set DNS on this server. Than I edit root folder in httpd.conf from `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/html/example.com/`.

I want to create subdomain like dev.example.com. I create new DNS record with this subdomain.

How can I set access with this domain to `/var/www/html/dev.example.com/` on my server?